# Ubuntu Server 17.10 watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 22s!

Tags: server, nvidia, 17.10, 64-bit, amd-processor

I am having a soft lookup issue with both of my new machine, each configured identical..  Tomahawk B350 Motherboard, AMD Rizen 1800x, 64GB Corsair Velocity RAM, Samsung EVO pro 960 1TB M.2 (with another Samsung 1TB SSD drive on SATA).  GOLD 650w Power supplies, GeForce GTX 1050..

I had to use Artful because of a fix for the B350 MB's

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:        17.10
Codename:       artful
```

Syslog:

```
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.454881] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#5 stuck for 22s! [kworker/5:1:4253]
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.454945] Modules linked in: ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 nf_conntrack_netlink nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 xt_addrtype iptable_filter xt_conntrack nf_nat nf_conntrack br_netfilter bridge stp llc aufs snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic edac_mce_amd kvm snd_hda_intel irqbypass snd_hda_codec wmi_bmof snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm i2c_piix4 snd_timer ccp snd soundcore shpchp tpm_infineon 8250_dw mac_hid ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear nouveau mxm_wmi video crct10dif_pclmul i2c_algo_bit crc32_pclmul
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.454982]  ttm ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt aesni_intel fb_sys_fops aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd drm r8169 nvme ahci mii libahci nvme_core wmi gpio_amdpt gpio_generic
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.454994] CPU: 5 PID: 4253 Comm: kworker/5:1 Not tainted 4.13.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.454995] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. AB350-Gaming 3/AB350-Gaming 3-CF, BIOS F7 06/16/2017
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455000] Workqueue: events netstamp_clear
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455002] task: ffff934bca600000 task.stack: ffffa624916c8000
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455005] RIP: 0010:smp_call_function_many+0x24a/0x270
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455006] RSP: 0018:ffffa624916cbcc0 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff10
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455008] RAX: ffff934c1ee272d0 RBX: ffff934c1ed63a00 RCX: 0000000000000008
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455009] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff934c1e828128
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455010] RBP: ffffa624916cbcf8 R08: ffffffffffffff00 R09: 000000000000ffdf
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455011] R10: ffffd1f47f5e5b80 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000010
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455011] R13: 0000000000000010 R14: ffffffffb6e33210 R15: 0000000000000000
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455013] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff934c1ed40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455014] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455014] CR2: 00007ff67c010b88 CR3: 0000000fd6002000 CR4: 00000000003406e0
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455015] Call Trace:
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455020]  ? netif_receive_skb_internal+0x28/0x3f0
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455022]  ? arch_unregister_cpu+0x30/0x30
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455024]  ? netif_receive_skb_internal+0x29/0x3f0
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455025]  on_each_cpu+0x2d/0x60
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455027]  ? netif_receive_skb_internal+0x28/0x3f0
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455028]  text_poke_bp+0x6a/0xf0
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455030]  __jump_label_transform.isra.0+0x10b/0x120
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455032]  arch_jump_label_transform+0x32/0x50
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455034]  __jump_label_update+0x68/0x80
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455036]  jump_label_update+0xae/0xc0
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455038]  __static_key_slow_dec+0x4e/0xa0
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455040]  static_key_slow_dec+0x22/0x50
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455041]  static_key_disable+0x21/0x30
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455042]  netstamp_clear+0x34/0x40
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455045]  process_one_work+0x1e7/0x410
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455047]  worker_thread+0x4b/0x420
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455049]  kthread+0x125/0x140
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455050]  ? process_one_work+0x410/0x410
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455052]  ? kthread_create_on_node+0x70/0x70
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455054]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Feb 22 17:09:06 srv1 kernel: [50911.455056] Code: 77 35 00 39 05 bc ad 34 01 89 c1 0f 8e 3d fe ff ff 48 98 48 8b 13 48 03 14 c5 e0 e3 f6 b7 48 89 d0 8b 52 18 83 e2 01 74 0a f3 90 <8b> 50 18 83 e2 01 75 f6 eb b9 48 c7 c2 20 08 26 b8 4c 89 e6 89
```

Originally I thought if I rebooted every morning at 3:00AM it would stop the freeze ups because they would lockup every week after being idle..  But that did not help..

Anything I can do to troubleshoot this further?